# convert angular FOV to FOV in km

Tags: geometry, fieldofview

I need to calculate the FOV [km].

the angular FOV is = 98 x 98° and
the distance of object is = 86km

```
FOV [km] = (tan(98/2) * 180 / pi) * 86
```

gives negative results. Where could be my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `pi/180` multiplier inside parentheses, it should be applied to angle

```
FOV [km] = tan(98/2 * pi / 180) * 86 * 2 = 198 km
```

Note x2 for full range